Definite vs indefinite articles in these examples
Let's say we have 4 versions of a sentence:

Divide fruits into apples and oranges.

Divide the fruits into the apples and the oranges.

Divide fruits into the apples and the oranges.

Divide the fruits into apples and oranges.


Are all of these sentences possible and grammatically correct? More generally what I was wondering about is whether if we have a sentence in the form of "Divide group A into subgroups a and b", then if the group A is definite, do the subgroups a and b must always be definite? (And conversely, if the group A is indefinite then do the subgroups a and b must always be indefinite?)
And also I have another related question, I'm not sure if I have to make a new post to ask more than 1 question or not, if I do then I would like an answer for just the first one. Again, we have 4 versions of a sentence:

Identify fruits that are edible and the ones that aren't.

Identify the fruits that are edible and the ones that aren't.

Identify fruits that are edible and ones that aren't.

Identify the fruits that are edible and ones that aren't.


Are all of these sentences possible and grammatically correct? I think the second one is correct, the first one I'm not sure about. The last 2 I think are unlikely to be correct, but I'm not completely sure.

Welcome to ELU. I've marked this question as a duplicate because the answers at the other question answer this one. If you cannot find an answer there which fits your examples and their context here, please [edit] this question to give more details. Note that the context of the sentence will indicate whether articles are necessary; conversely, the presence or absence of articles can alter the meaning or application of the sentence.

The trouble with coming up with example sentences for analysis is that it is very common for even the grammatical example/s to sound artificial and unnatural (especially without a contextualising phrase/clause or two). And this makes 'identifying the correct option/s' quite an unenviable exercise.  'Separate the apples from the oranges.' // 'Identify the fruits in this picture / list / box that are edible and the ones that aren't.' ('The' conveys the sense of 'all those'; it must be balanced by a second 'the'.) // [Apparently, inedible fruits include Osage Orange, Silverbell, and Wahoo!]
